# npm install -g @angular/cli fails everytime

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have node version 8.0.0 and npm version 5.1.0 and running on Ubuntu 16.04.2. But when I try to install Angular, I get the same outcome:

```
zlib.js:455
    var newReq = self._handle.write(flushFlag,
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of null
at Zlib.callback (zlib.js:455:34)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: asap@2.0.5 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/asap):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/asap/-/asap-2.0.5.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: acorn@5.1.1 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/acorn):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-5.1.1.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles/-/ansi-styles-2.2.1.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/thetapc/.npm/_logs/2017-07-07T05_49_06_748Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The latest node v8.x fixes a zlib-related issue in v8.0.0. Try upgrading.

Comment: @mscdex Thank you. I tried it but didn't seem to want to install. I went with 6.11.0 and it worked. But in all honesty, latest 8.x could have worked if I had more patience.

Answer (score 0):

Run `yarn install` inside the new created project to solve this issue. Hope it helps someone.